# Outputting argument but no new line feature in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way how to remove the property of the print() function in Python that makes end of line after outputting its argument? Or is there a different function to do the output of argument but no the end line?

To illustrate this, lets say I want to output the English alphabet on one line. The following code prints every letter on a new line:

```
for x in range(26):
    print(chr(x+97))
```

While the second code prints it the way requested, but by concatenation of strings instead:

```
s=''
for x in range(26):
    s+=chr(x+97)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(“Hello”, end=“”)
print(1)
```

Output: Hello1

Hope this helps :) the default value of end is “\n” and you can change it to anything you want.